# ZF2 - overriding navigation menu view helper function

Tags: php, zend-framework2, view-helpers

I'm trying to extend the `Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu` helper class with my own and override `accept` function. Based on [ZF2 register custom helper for navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184067/zf2-register-custom-helper-for-navigation) question, my Menu helper class looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace Application\View\Helper\Navigation;

use Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu as ZendMenu;
use Zend\Navigation\Page\AbstractPage;

class Menu extends ZendMenu
{
    public function accept(AbstractPage $page, $recursive = true)
    {
        $accept = true;

        return $accept;
    }
}
```

In `module.config.php` I have added this:

```
'navigation_helpers' => array (
    'invokables' => array(
        'menu' => 'Application\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu',
    ),
),
```

This code works fine in general case, but `accept` function in my class is not called when a partial layout is used to render menu. The problem might be with calling `renderPartial()` vs `renderMenu()` in the background, but I'm not sure how to solve it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this tutorial](https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/11/18/zend-framework-2-dynamic-navigation-using-zend-navigation/) by Samsonasik.  I use a hack of his example to develop two-dimensional menus.  While the meat of the tutorial is about dynamic menus, how he renders the menu may be of help.

Samsonasik calls the menu like this:

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
<?php echo $this->navigation('Navigation')->menu()->setUlClass('nav'); ?>
</div>
```

In my hack, I call my menu like this:

```
<?php

// ...

echo "<div class='collapse navbar-collapse'>";
    echo "<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>";
        echo $this->navigation('mainNavigation')
                  ->menu()
                  ->setPartial('partial/menu')
                  ->render();
    echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was in my partial layout for rendering menu items. I was checking `if($this->navigation('Zend\Navigation\Sidebar')->accept($page))` instead of `if($this->navigation('Zend\Navigation\Sidebar')->menu()->accept($page))` and that's why my `accept` function wasn't executed.